# Combining multiple Dataframes into one and filling in missing information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame filled with information about some projects, such as status, assignee, priority, etc... I have a bunch of these DataFrames, each representing those projects at different weeks in a year.

I want to count how many times each status occurs in each DataFrame. I can do this using `df.groupby("status").size().to_frame()`, but this gets me the info for one frame at a time in separate DataFrames.

How can I combine these DataFrames together to get one big DataFrame? (Each row would look like: Date, Status, Count) Additionally, if a status occurs in one of the sub-sets, but not in others, I need to add that status to all the others with a count of 0. Is this possible? I have not been able to find another answer or set of answers that explain this.

Comment: Consider adding dataframe sample and expected output.

Comment: You might want to look at [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for the first part of your question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood exactly what you would like to do, but to combine two frames df and df2, say, you can use

```
df2.set_index(pd.Series([i for i in range(len(df),len(df)+len(df2))]), inplace=True)
df_concat = pd.concat([df, df2])
```

and then get the counts for the combined dataframe:

```
df_concat.groupby(df_concat.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'counts'})
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're driving at with that first line, what is the point of the set_index operation? I think this is close, but still has the problem of not all possible column values being represented for all dates.

(Ex: If one of the concatenated DataFrames has a value of "Closed", but another of the DataFrames does not, the final DataFrame needs to have a row for the date that did not with a count of 0 for the "Closed" status.

Comment: The set_index operation is just meant to make sure the index column does not restart at 0 for the second DataFrame in the concatenation. Did I get you right that all of your DataFrames have the same column structure? I agree with @Poojan that it would help if you posted an example of your input plus desired output.